# Resizing tkinter widgets in an application

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to build a navigator application with tkinter and am very new to making GUIs and using tkinter in general. I can't seem to figure out how to resize the widgets nicely when the entire window is resized. Resizing currently works as shown in the gif below.

[image]

The top description is a tkinter Message widget, the middle navigator tree is a Checklist, the two buttons are regular Buttons, and the text beneath the Buttons is a Label object. I am placing these in the tkinter root with the .grid() method and using ipadx, ipady, padx and pady to size them as necessary.

I would like the text and buttons to not disappear if the window is resized somewhat similar to the Checklist object. And ideally when resizing the window I would like the text to word wrap and make room for itself. I can set a minimum size for the window just fine to make sure everything fits but resizing still isn't elegant. I can't seem to figure out word wrapping at all either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is example code that will help you understand how resizing works.
I sugest you use `Grid.rowconfigure()` and `Grid.columnconfigure()`

example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Grid, Button

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("resize button")
root.geometry("500x500")


# here you need to put on what do you want to use row configure, index(row) and weight
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)  # we use on root, row=0 weight=1
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)

#configure 2nd row
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 1, weight=1)


#configure 3rd row
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 2, weight=1)

#configure 2nd column
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 1, weight=1)

button1 = Button(root, text="Button1")
button2 = Button(root, text="Button2")
button3 = Button(root, text="Button3")

button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
button2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
button3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")

button1_1 = Button(root, text="Button1_1")
button2_1 = Button(root, text="Button2_1")
button3_1 = Button(root, text="Button3_1")

button1_1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
button2_1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
button3_1.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```